# How can I load an image from a changing path environment after building an .app with cargo-bundle?

Tags: rust

I'm using [cargo-bundle](https://github.com/burtonageo/cargo-bundle) to create an .app bundle for my Rust application built with fltk-rs.
There are assets in the application like images. While I'm developing, accessing these assets is no problem.

main.rs:

```rust
let mut my_img = SharedImage::load("imgs/smiley.png").unwrap();
```

```
.
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── app_icon_design.psd
├── imgs
│   └── smiley.PNG <--get this image
├── src
│   ├── app_icon.png
│   ├── app_icon@2x.png
│   ├── icon32x32.png
│   └── main.rs
└── target
    ├── CACHEDIR.TAG
    ├── debug
    └── release
```

I then bundle to an .app with `cargo build --release` which gives me the following directory structure inside of my .app:

```
.
├── Info.plist
├── MacOS
│   └── build_to_app_bundle <--my executable
└── Resources
    └── imgs
        └── smiley.PNG<--get this image now
```

Now my application needs to get the image file from the `/Resources` folder:

```rust
println!("my resources folder is: {:?}", std::env::current_exe().unwrap().parent().unwrap().join(Path::new("Resources")));
let my_resources_path = std::env::current_exe().unwrap().parent().unwrap().join(Path::new("Resources"));
```

How can I make it so that every time I want to load an image from a path I do not need to explicitly reference the `Resources` value?

Comment: Can you share your `Cargo.toml` file? Also, why can't you just write a function that loads an image from the `/Resources` directory for you?